# Remove the ability to resize

Tags: c#, winforms

Goal:    Don't want the user to make changes in the program's size.

Problem:    Don't know how to remove that icone thing that allows user to resize the screen.

[image: hello]

Comment: Window size == program size. Uh-huh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should set the [`FormBorderStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) property of your form to [a style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41.aspx) that forbids resizing (any of the `Fixedxxx` styles will do).

Still, remember that, especially for main windows, often locking the size of the window is not a good choice in terms of program usability; resize logic is often boring and not easy to get right, but in general it's worth the effort (and the various `Dock` and `Fill` properties of the controls are there to help).

Answer (score 2):

Set the FormBorderStyle to Fixed Single:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to set ShowMinimize & Maximize to false as well (in addition to the form border style)